# When I run a module function, it freezes the program (Python)

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

**Context**
I'm writing a parser in Python and have lexer and AST files in other modules

In my main.py file, I have this code:

```
from parserdef import Parser

def repl():
  parser = Parser()
  while True:
    source = input("-> ")

    if source == "exit":
      pass

    try:
      program = parser.produceAST(source)
      print(program.body)
    except Exception as e:
      print(f"Error: {e}")

repl()
```

Whenever I run it and type something like "4 + 5", it freezes for something like 2 minutes and then outputs just `Error:`

The code for the parser is:

```
import astdef as ast
import lexer 

class Parser:
  def __init__(self):
    self.tokens = []

  def notEOF(self) -> bool:   
    return type(self.tokens[0]) != lexer.TokenType.EOF
  
  def at(self) -> lexer.Token:
    return self.tokens[0]
  
  def eat(self) -> lexer.Token:
    previous = lexer.shift(self.tokens)
    return previous
  
  def produceAST(self, source) -> ast.Program:
    self.tokens = lexer.tokenise(source)
    program = ast.Program([])

    # Parse until end of file
    while self.notEOF():
      program.body.append(self.parseStatement())
    
    return program
 
  def parseStatement(self) -> ast.Statement:
    return self.parseExpression()
  
  def parseExpression(self) -> ast.Exp:
    return self.parsePrimaryExpression

  def parsePrimaryExpression(self) -> ast.Exp:
    token = type(self.at())

    if token == lexer.TokenType.IDENT:
      return ast.Identifier(self.eat().value)
    elif token == lexer.TokenType.NUM:
      return ast.NumericLiteral(float(self.eat().value)) # mb error?
    else:
      RuntimeError(f"token: {self.at()}")
```

So my question is: What takes it so long to complete this function and why does it produce an empty error?

/// Edit

the code for lexer :

```
from enum import Enum

class TokenType(Enum):
    NUM = 0
    IDENT = 1
    EQU = 2
    OPENPAREN = 3
    CLOSEPAREN = 4
    BINOP = 5
    LET = 6
    EOF = 7 # Signifies end of a file

Keywords = {
    "let": TokenType.LET
}

class Token:
    def __init__(self, value, type: TokenType):
        self.value = value
        self.type = type

def shift(vector):
    currentChar = vector[0]
    vector.pop(0)
    return currentChar

def token(value, type) -> Token:
    return [value, type]

def isAlpha(source: str):
    return source.upper() != source.lower()

def isInt(source):
    character = ord(source[0])
    bounds = [ord('0'), ord('9')]
    return character >= bounds[0] and character <= bounds[1]

def isSkippable(source):
    return source == " " or source == "\n" or source == "\t"

def tokenise(source: str):
    tokens = []
    _source = source.split()

    # Build each token until the end of the string
    while len(_source) > 0:
        if _source[0] == '(':
            tokens.append(token(shift(_source), TokenType.OPENPAREN))
        elif _source[0] == ')':
            tokens.append(token(shift(_source), TokenType.CLOSEPAREN)) 
        elif _source[0] == '+' or _source[0] == '-' or _source[0] == '*' or _source[0] == '/':
            tokens.append(token(shift(_source), TokenType.BINOP)) 
        elif _source[0] == '=':
            tokens.append(token(shift(_source), TokenType.EQU))
            
        else:
            # Handle multicharacter tokens

            # Build number token
            if isInt(_source[0]):
                num = ""
                while len(_source) > 0 and isInt(_source):
                    num += shift(_source)
                
                tokens.append(token(num, TokenType.NUM))
            
            # Build identifier token
            elif isAlpha(_source[0]):
                ident = ""
                while len(_source) > 0 and isAlpha(_source[0]):
                    ident += shift(_source)
                
                # Check for reserved keywords
                if ident not in Keywords:
                    tokens.append(token(ident, TokenType.IDENT))
                else:
                    tokens.append(token(ident, Keywords[ident]))

            elif _source[0] == '$':
                shift(_source)
                ident = ""
                while len(_source) > 0 and isAlpha(_source[0]):
                    ident += shift(_source)
                
                # Check for reserved keywords
                if ident == '':
                    raise SyntaxError("identifer")
                elif ident not in Keywords:
                    tokens.append(token(ident, TokenType.IDENT))
                else:
                    tokens.append(token(ident, Keywords[ident]))

            elif isSkippable(_source[0]):
                shift(_source)
            
            else:
                print(f"unrecognised character: {_source[0]}")

    tokens.append(token("EndOfFile", TokenType.EOF))

    return tokens
```

the code for astdef :

```
from enum import Enum

class NodeType(Enum):
  PROGRAM = 0
  NUMERICLITERAL = 1
  IDENTIFIER = 2
  BINARYEXP = 3
  CALLEXP = 4
  UNARYEXP = 5
  FUNCDEC = 6

class Statement:
  def __init__(self, kind: NodeType):
    self.kind = kind
  
class Program(Statement):
  def __init__(self, body: list):
    self.kind = "PROGRAM"
    self.body = body

class Exp(Statement):
  pass

class BinaryExp(Exp):
  def __init__(self, left: Exp, right: Exp, operator: str):
    self.kind = "BINARYEXP"
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.operator = operator

class Identifier(Exp):
  def __init__(self, symbol: str):
    self.kind = "IDENTIFIER"
    self.symbol = symbol

class NumericLiteral(Exp):
  def __init__(self, value: int):
    self.kind = "NUMERICLITERAL"
    self.value = value
```

Comment: What are the packages `astdef` and `lexer`? I am unable to find them.

Comment: They are my own packages. Should I add the code for them to the question?

Comment: I was trying to run your code and can't without them, so yes, you need to provide them in some way. A link to your github would be fine if they are not core to your question.

Comment: Instead of print the error, for development you could use:
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
that print a lot of more info

Comment: I recommend adding some `print()` statements to see where your code is executing. This might help you see what part of the code takes the most amount of time. I suspect that your parser or lexer are sub-optimal or have an error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will do. I just added the code for the modules if you can be bothered to look through them. Thanks for the input anyway

Comment: I fixed the code formatting for you.

Comment: Now when I [run your code](https://replit.com/@codeguru/SevereMadeupNagware) and enter "4+5", I get "Error: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found". My guess is that you are doing `ord("4+5")` which is illegal. You will need to debug your code to figure out where this is happening. I recommend reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for a reminder of some very good debugging tips to get you started.

Comment: yeah i noticed that aswell, but the freeze occurred when i spaced the terms out (like ”4 + 5”)

Comment: With that said, why are you using `ord()` at all? That seems like the incorrect thing to do in a parser for mathematical expressions. At least if you want to turn a string `"123"` into the integer value `123`, it is the wrong solution.

Comment: I guess you want to allow either version of the input (`4+5` or `4 + 5`). In either case, you will need to debug your code to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: i was using it to check the unicode of the character and if it was a number then it would make a token of a number

Comment: Note that you can comare strings directly without applying `ord()`. Something like `'0' <= x <= '9'` should do the trick.

Comment: If you remove the use of `ord()` as I just suggested, you will no longer get the error on the input without spaces. But this actually only hides the problem. I think there is a problem with your lexer where it doesn't properly create the correct tokens for the parser.

Comment: In parsdef on line 41 `return ast.NumericLiteral(float(self.eat().value))` you are using a float, but NumericLiteral() is expecting an int.

Comment: in astdef you probably should use `super().__init__(kind)`?

Comment: in lexer on line 52 you split the source but you probably just want to have the caracters in a list, right? Something like `_source = list(source)`

Comment: @Ovski Or just iterate over the characters in the string directly.